# MySQL: Unique combination key if field is blank/zero/null

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, unique

I have a simple database table which I'd like to keep simple (instead of breaking it into 3-5 smaller ones).  For simplicity's sake, here's what it looks like, with a few sample entries:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| memberId | guestName | guestAge |  date  |
+----------+-----------+----------+--------+
| 123      |           |          | 1/2/13 |
+----------+-----------+----------+--------+
|          | Bob       | 30       | 1/2/13 |
+----------+-----------+----------+--------+
```

What I'm wondering: **is there a way to enforce unique pairing of memberIds and dates, but not forcing guestNames or ages?**

Notes:

1. We could have multiple guests named Bob, age 30 on 1/2/13, thereby making a unique key across all the fields not a workable solution.
2. I realize I could split the guests and members into separate tables, but this significantly complicates the rest of the problem (which I have left off already to simplify).  It's simply not worth it at this point.

So my question: is this possible, or an (understandable) limitation of the MySQL unique key?

Comment: Just as a side note: You probably want to store the date of birth instead of the age, as your birthday changes less frequently than your age

Comment: What a horrible reason to justify bad db design.

Comment: T3H40: these are for one-off nights. If a guest returns they're going to be re-entered each visit by the inviting party.  Since all that matters is age range (example: <21, 21+) prompting the user for the date itself is more troublesome than it's worth.  
  
---  
  
popovitsj: I understand it's not the best design, but it allows a single person-night pairing to be entered as 1 reservation request.  Otherwise we extract all data common to a request, each member to a memberRequest table (with memberId and date, uniquely keyed), another similar table for guests, a pairing table for each, etc.